# How to send a jms message through a html form to a jms reciever??

Tags: tibco-ems

I have created a html form where i want to send a message over to a jms receiver in TIBCO.
If it can be done through java script,can you please tell me the syntax of the same??
Please help me!!

Comment: i just want to post a message through a HTML from and want a jms receiver to pick it up!! Any help please??

Comment: Welcome to SO, please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: Hi,i have tried giving the jndi name and username and password of the jms connection specified but i'm unable to trigger it!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TIBCO EMS as interfaces for : [C, COBOL, Java EE, and .NET](http://www.tibco.com/products/automation/messaging/enterprise-messaging/enterprise-message-service/default.jsp).
They require code (libraries) from TIBCO, under license (might be included when you acquire EMS).

For example, to submit a message to EMS from Java, you must use the JMS framework (part of Java), but you code still require the (non-free) EMS .jar.

To submit to EMS from a Web Form, you would typically use some form of integration, like a Web Service (possibly Java or BusinessWorks based), that transfers the data to EMS.

Note : Some other messaging products, like ActiveMQ, support a [direct AJAX interface](http://activemq.apache.org/ajax.html).